# What port does sending tweets via the Twitter api use?

Tags: oracle, twitter, plsql, port

I would like to use the code [at this link](http://kubilaykara.blogspot.com/2013/02/send-tweets-from-oracle-with-oauth.html) to send tweets from Oracle PL/SQL. However I have to convince the network administrator to open up the port on the DMZ firewall in order to do this. So my question is what port would that code need so that I can tell them to open that port. Is it just port 80 for html, so nothing has to be opened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's this: [Twitter Development Talk](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/twitter-development-talk/jjPnDgRBNsU/)

`The Twitter API runs on standard web service ports: Port 80 for non-secure traffic and Port 443 for SSL-based traffic.`

Comment: Does twitter send anything back or is it only one way communication from me to twitter?

Comment: We're talking about web requests, aren't we? Then likely, yes, Twitter will send data back to you in response to your request.